# .length() vs .getText().length() vs .getText().toString().length()

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview

For example in the code below `a` and `b` and `c` are equal.

```
EditText editText;
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edttxt);

editText.setText("1234");

int a, b, c;
a = editText.length();
b = editText.getText().length();
c = editText.getText().toString().length();
```

What is difference between `length()` and `getText().length()` and `getText().toString().length()`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`.length()` and `getText().length()` are identical in [their current implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java).

`.getText().toString().length()` will convert the `CharSequence` into a plain `String`, then compute its length. I would expect that to return the same value as the other two in many cases. However, if the `CharSequence` is something like a `SpannedString`, I cannot rule out the possibility that there is some type of formatting span (e.g., `ImageSpan`) that affects length calculations.

Answer (score 8):

It's a matter of performance.
`length` will do exactly the same as `getText` and `length` it just saves you from typing `getText()`.
From class `TextView` which `EditText` extends:

```
public CharSequence getText() {
    return mText;
}

/**
 * Returns the length, in characters, of the text managed by this TextView
 */
public int length() {
    return mText.length();
}
```

As to `toString`, it's the same, however, any conversion you make (`CharSequence` => `String`) will cost you a tiny bit in performance (so little you'll probably not notice it).

Also, when you convert stuff you have to look out for null pointer exceptions, maybe not in this instance but generally speaking.

To answer the question, just use length()

Comment: Tiny bits add up to gargantuan time slices. If this would be done in data that was yet to be presented (say in a background worker thread) for thousands of times, unnecessarily producing Strings and leaving them to the GC is a very silly idea. I just wanted to make it clear that although a single conversion will be OK on any platform (for this amount of characters), if you perform too many of them it will take time.

Comment: You are absolutely correct mafagafogigante, this is usually not the case. however, best practice dictates that we don't convert when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 5):

1. `length()` :- `length()` function is an inherited method for `EditView` which is getting inherited by `TextView` that returns the length, in characters, of the text managed by this `EditView`. So, it will return the length of text that user put into the `EditView` Contorl.
2. `getText().length()` :- here in this statement `length()` function does not belongs to `EditView` class . In actual this `length()` Function belong to `CharSequence` class because `getText()` return a `CharSequence` object.  So, again this function `length()` will return the number of **characters** in this sequence.
3. `.getText().toString().length()` :- here `toString()` method Convert the `CharSequence` Object into a plain immutable `String` Object. So, here `length()` function belongs to `String` class which also return the length of `String` object

Comment: Please Remove All Your Bizarre Capitalization of Nearly Every Word.

Comment: as you can see from the code in my answers taken from the source of EditText, 1 and 2 are identical since they both use  CharSequence length. it doesn't matter who they inherit from but what object length is being called on.